User activity monitoring, Can it be done and how ? - Clicks, pages, tabs and components entered, action taken, etc
I have a Sales and Financial Services environment that works with banking and as such, auditing is quite heavy.
Having that said, I need to find a way to be able to monitor and register somewhere in my Salesforce org, per user, where he clicked, what pages he visited, what he did, etc.
For example, i have in my org the capability to send text messages and emails, do reports, etc. I would like for my environment to record that the user entered an Account page, selected something, sent a text message (not the message itself, only that he sent one), visited X and Y pages, etc.
Anyone 'round here with experience doing these tasks?
Appreciate all the help.

What you're looking for is called Event Monitoring. It will answer many of the questions you have. You should be able to purchase this feature in the Your Account tab in Setup, or you can contact your account executive.

for auditing past 30 days, we coupled our Event Monitoring license with an third party event log collector (in our case, SumoLogic) that can store logs for a much longer period of time and has dashboards and a  query language

I already have Event Monitoring, but unfortunately, it does not monitor which page a user visited, which actions he took when it comes to using functionality of our objects, etc. the EventLogFiles dont have this information when it comes to clicks
